# Http POST parameter Awesomnium Post Parameters vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, awesomium

I want to POST data with Awesomnium control - vb.net 
 
I founded this code written in c# :

```
public class CustomResourceInterceptor : ResourceInterceptor
{
    protected override ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        request.Method = "POST";
        var bytes = "Appending some text to the request";
        request.AppendUploadBytes(bytes, (uint) bytes.Length);
        request.AppendExtraHeader("custom-header", "this is a custom header");

        return null;
    }
}


public MainWindow()
{
    WebCore.Started += WebCoreOnStarted;
    InitializeComponent();
}

    private void WebCoreOnStarted(object sender, CoreStartEventArgs coreStartEventArgs)
    {
        var interceptor = new CustomResourceInterceptor();

        WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = interceptor;
        //webView is a WebControl on my UI, but you should be able to create your own WebView off WebCore
        webView.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

but I did not understand how to convert it into vb.net code 
, any help ?

Thanks

Comment: The least-obvious issue is probably the event wireup (WebCore.Started += WebCoreOnStarted) - use "AddHandler WebCore.Started, AddressOf WebCoreOnStarted"